# How to make a POST request in koa-http-request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, koa, koa2

I am unable to make a POST method request with . I am unable to send a request object with it.

For example see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43552582). Here only GET request is being made. But I want to make a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a POST request to an another host it would be easier to use some libraries dedicated to this task like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [request](https://github.com/request/request).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. When I tried to make a POST request I was receiving `undefined` as the value of the `body` object.

I ended up not using `koa-http-request` as the example provided in your link. I have used both `koa-bodyparser` and `koa-router` middlewares instead:

```
const Koa = require('koa');

const KoaRouter = require('koa-router');
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');

const app = new Koa();
const router = new KoaRouter();

// =====  M i d d l e w a r e s  =====
// Body parser 
app.use(bodyParser());
// Router
app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());

// ...

const addItem = async (context) => {
  const body = await context.request.body;

  // Now you can access the body object
  console.log(body)

}

// ...

router.post('/', addItem);
```

In my case it had worked as it supposed to. :)